# Angular UI router href returned absolute URL lacks path

Tags: angular-ui-router

I'm using angular-ui-router, when browsing on my app, on URL

```
http://localhost:8080/referential/browse.action#/referential/collectivity/38470/181/services
```

I can call

```
$state.href(COLLECTIVITY_STATE, {collectivityId: collectivityId})
```

and I get

```
#/referential/collectivity/38470/181/services
```

That's fine but I want a full URL (ready to bookmark or send by email), according to the documentation, i add a parameter to href call:

```
$state.href(COLLECTIVITY_STATE, {collectivityId: collectivityId}, {absolute: true})
```

but what I get is

```
http://localhost:8080/#/referential/collectivity/38470/121/services
```

which is not the expected first URL: the path is lacking. How should I get the full URL?

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
$location.absUrl();
```

to return the absolute URL (which includes the domain and protocol).

Be sure to include $location in your controller or factory dependency list.

```
app.factory("test", function($location)
{
     console.log($location.absURL());
});
```